# Uso del comando -D en el comando de compilacion de un Makefile?

Tags: gcc, makefile

hoy nos hicieron crear un programa en C, y para compilarlo desde la bash nos dieron este "Makefile", pero no logro entender que significa -D en -DMY_SOURCE_FILE. Lo unico que logre dilucidar es que dentro el programa en C, llaman MY_SOURCE_FILE y contiene la string "string_master". Es a caso la declaracion de una constante o de un typedef como intruccion de compilacion? Alguien me lo sabe explicar?

N=hello0

M=string_master

CMP=gc_string_master

SCRPT=check_master.bash

all: $(N) $(M)

test_master : $(M) $(CMP)

```
    ./$(SCRPT) $(CMP) $(M) m
    ./$(SCRPT) $(CMP) $(M) f
    ./$(SCRPT) $(CMP) $(M) p
    ./$(SCRPT) $(CMP) $(M) fp
```

$(M): $(M).c

```
gcc -o $(M) -DMY_SOURCE_FILE='"$(M)"' $(M).c
```

$(N): $(N).c

```
gcc -o $(N) $(N).c
```

clean:

```
/bin/rm -f a.out *.o $(M) $(N) diff_*.txt
```

tgz: clean

```
cd .. ; tar cvzf $(N).tgz $(N)
```

Comment: Pues no es que lo hayas intentado mucho, un simple `man gcc` nos informa sobre las opciones que soporta. Basta con filtrar todas las `-D`: `man gcc | fgrep -- -D`. En la primera línea lo tienes: `[-Dmacro[=defn]...]`.

Comment: Muchas gracias...si no lo intente mucho es por que no sabia como hacerlo :-)